# IpTables inside Docker Container to control Subcontainer

Tags: docker, iptables

I am currently working on a network filter for microservices inside a Docker container.

The architecture is as follows:

```
host
    container A                        // in bridge network docker0
        (Create network (bridge, name: testnet) for microservices)
        (Manage IpTable rules for microservices)
        microservice A                 // started in custom bridge network (interface name: testnet)
        microservice B                 // started in custom bridge network (interface name: testnet)
             ...
    container B (Some other functionality)
    container C (Some other functionality)
        ...
```

The whole system consists of multiple containers, with one of them having again multiple subcontainers (microservices) in it.

Now I want to restrict the access to the microservices without restricting the access of the other containers with IpTables.

What I am doing now is creating a Docker Network for the containers in container A and the system in container A is responsible for handling the IpTable rules. The IpTable management needs to be done here because of other system requirements.

How is it possible to apply IpTable rules inside a docker container to the DOCKER-USER chain?

Minimised Dockerfile of Container A:

```
FROM node:14

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y iptables build-essential

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --add-cap=NET_ADMIN -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock containera
```

The microservices are started like:

```
docker run --network testnet microservicea
```

An example rule I want to apply:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i testnet -s xxx.xx.xxx -j REJECT
```

But I get an Error here because the chain DOCKER-USER does not exist inside the container.

I already tried installing iptables inside the container, but the chains are emtpy inside the container and DOCKER-USER is missing:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Adding a rule to INPUT or OUTPUT has not effect on the microservices.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "subcontainer" in docker; docker is a "flat" containerization architecture.  Running docker "inside" docker simply runs docker within the same place as running docker "next to" docker.  What you're doing here strikes me as messy because IP Tables are *primarily* a kernel implemented thing, and kernel space is shared across docker containers.  As you clearly know, docker uses IPTables rules to implement `--expose`.  Not saying it's impossible, but take care not to hose up networking on the underlying host.  VM concepts don't map well to containers.

Comment: Yes the system is a bit messy, but I need to implement this inside an existing system, so I have to accept the architecture as it is. Basically, I just need to add rules to the DOCKER-USER chain from inside a container, which needs to be in a bridge network (I think I read somewhere that this is easily possible if the container is started with --net host, but this is not possible here). Because of the system architecture it cannot be done on the host.